# how to install Lubuntu on windows 7

Tags: boot, virtualbox

i recently installed lubuntu 18.04 on a 32 bit laptop (toshiba) through a vbox, and it gave me these problems:
1. my laptop /vbox doesn't  have the option for lubuntu
2. cannot boot lubuntu but there are other linux options (apart from lubuntu)

what should i do with this latest version of lubuntu on my vbox (lubuntu is a guest on windows 7) since lubuntu is not set as an option on the choices?

many thanks

Answer (score 1):

The option to select the type of OS is just so that VirtualBox can determine the [default settings necessary for the guest OS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26217_01/E26796/html/qs-create-vm.html), and hence selecting Ubuntu on the menu will suffice.

- Open VirtualBox and click on New.
- Choose your guest OS and architecture (32bit and Ubuntu in your case)
- Set your Base Memory (RAM)
- Click next to get to the VM Storage Size. Input the size you require and click on "Create"
- On the VirtualBox main window, select "start" and pick your install media. In this case, select the ISO of Lubuntu 18.04 that you've [downloaded](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/18.04/release/lubuntu-18.04-desktop-i386.iso)
- Finish the installation as usual
- Unmount the ISO after you're done

You can additionally install Guest Additions as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/22745/17722).